# Converting \n to String without \\n

Tags: java, string

How can I convert `"\n"` into a `char[]`? I want to do this because I want to do some string manipulation when `\n` is entered in the method as input. I know that if `\\n` is entered then the output will be `\n` as a string. I want to implement a method to take in input as `\n` not `\\n` to get the string result.

tests:

```
    char[] arr = new char[2];
    String str = "\n";
    arr = str.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(arr.length);
    for (char c : arr) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

ouput:

```
1
    // newline empty space
```

my reverse string method

```
public static String reverseStr(String str) {
        if ( str == null ) {
              return null;
        }
        int len = str.length();
        if (len <= 0) {
            return "";
        }
        char[] strArr = new char[len];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            strArr[count] = str.charAt(i);
            count++;
        }
        return new String(strArr);
    }
```

Comment: `\n` is a single character

Comment: In Java, "\n" can't be written. It gives compilation errors. Its always "\\n". Also, if you press enter, the input will be newline character. But if You enter \n, it won't.

Comment: the only way is whenever you found `newline`, you can manually add `strArr[count]='n' strArr[count]='\\'` but the array size will changed too

Comment: String str = "hi\nhello".replace("\n", "\\n");

Answer (score 0):

newlines are represented as 10 in ascii. you can try this.

```
char[] arr = new char[3];
            int str = 10;
            arr[0] = 'a';
            arr[1] = (char)str;
            arr[2] = 'c';
            System.out.println(arr.length);
            for (char c : arr) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using Stringbuilder 
String builder(StringBuilder has overloaded methods for char and Sting).

```
StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder();
     str.append('\n'); or
     str.append("\n");
```